# Cannot test for value of WP_DEBUG constant in functions.php

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to check if `WP_DEBUG` is `true` but I'm experiencing some weird behavior. I made a barebones `functions.php` for testing:

```
<?php

define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
if ( defined( 'WP_DEBUG' ) && WP_DEBUG === true ) {
    die( 'WP_DEBUG' );
}

define( 'TEST', true );
if ( defined( 'TEST' ) && TEST === true ) {
    die( 'TEST' );
}

?>
```

This script always dies with `TEST`. The `WP_DEBUG` condition never returns true. Any idea what's causing this weird behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` already defined in `wp_config.php` file. You dont need to define again. Remove this code `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` from `functions.php`.

and add this code `functions.php`.

```
if ( defined( 'WP_DEBUG' ) && WP_DEBUG === true ) {
    die( 'WP_DEBUG' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I thought you could redefine constants in PHP.